# Smarty plugin-like functionality within Spring MVC possible?

Tags: spring-mvc, plugins, smarty, portlet

I have a software design question. I am looking for Smarty plugins-like functionality in a Spring MVC app. Let me try to explain the case.

I am using Spring MVC to build a webapp and I want the system to be able to display application wide 'system messages' like

`<div class="sysmessage'>Your user profile is incomplete, please fix it</div>`

or

`<div class="sysmessage'>System down for maintenance next friday between 13:00 and 14:00</div>`

I already have a service method that returns system messages when the user needs to be informed of something. The normal approach to this (I think) would be to call the service method from each and every Controller method and add any system message to the model, display it in the main grid JSP and voila... application wide system messages.

But this approach seems so labour intensive. I would need to add the call to the service method to every controller method, add it to the model every time, etc..

My question: is there some kind of 'reversed' setup possible in Spring that resembles the Smarty plugin functionality? A smarty plugin is a piece of HTML/template code that is backed by PHP code. I need the same in my app. It would be much faster and cleaner if I could place a piece of JSP code that is backed by Java code in my template. I know a custom JSP tag basically does this, but I was wondering if there is something packed with Spring that can achieve the same. It seems like such a common scenario. I looked at Spring Protlet MVC, but I am not entirely sure if that fits my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

- Spring interceptor
- Tiles view preparer
- ServletAPI filter

In all cases, you will need to add some code to your jsp's to output the message in your page.
This would be best done in a tiles layout which is used by all the pages that should display the message.

Comment: Spring interceptor seems like a nice thing to figure out and learn and it fits my needs, so I will use that. Thanks.